# Scrapy concurrent or distributed crawls

Tags: concurrency, scrapy, distributed

I would like to use scrapy to crawl fairly large websites. In some cases I will already have the links to scrape and in others I will need to extract (crawl) them. I will also need to access a database twice when running. Once in order to determine if a url is required to be scraped (Spider middleware) and once in order to store the extracted information (Item pipeline). 
Ideally, I would be able to run concurrent or distributed crawls in order to speed things up. What is the recommended way to run concurrent or distributed crawls with scrapy?

Answer (score 0):

You should check [scrapy_redis](https://github.com/rolando/scrapy-redis).

It is very simple to implement. Your `scheduler` and `duplicate filter` will be store in a redis queue. All the spiders will work concurrently, and you should speed up your crawl time.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

The [Scrapy Cluster](https://scrapy-cluster.readthedocs.io) documentation contains a [page](https://scrapy-cluster.readthedocs.io/en/latest/topics/advanced/comparison.html) listing many existing Scrapy-based solutions for distributed crawls.